# What is the difference between "Distribution Worker" and "Distributing Worker"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, adjectives, present-participles

I cannot differentiate when I should use a noun like "distribution" as an adjective to another noun, or when should I use an "-ing" participle as an adjective. Could you please clarify the differences in the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

One may be a clerk or janitor in Distribution industry, the other may be a runner/courier for a newspaper. One works for distribution industry, the other performs distribution, possibly as one-person-department in another company.